# Applying a function to an array using Numpy when the function contains a condition

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am having a difficulty with applying a function to an array when the function contains a condition. I have an inefficient workaround and am looking for an efficient (fast) approach. In a simple example:

```
pts = np.linspace(0,1,11)
def fun(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Now, if I run:

```
result = fun(pts, pts)
```

then I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

raised at the `if x > y` line. My inefficient workaround, which gives the correct result but is too slow is:

```
result = np.full([len(pts)]*2, np.nan)
for i in range(len(pts)):
    for j in range(len(pts)):
        result[i,j] = fun(pts[i], pts[j])
```

What is the best way to obtain this in a nicer (and more importantly, faster) way?

I am having a difficulty with applying a function to an array when the function contains a condition. I have an inefficient workaround and am looking for an efficient (fast) approach. In a simple example:

```
pts = np.linspace(0,1,11)
def fun(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Now, if I run:

```
result = fun(pts, pts)
```

then I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

raised at the `if x > y` line. My inefficient workaround, which gives the correct result but is too slow is:

```
result = np.full([len(pts)]*2, np.nan)
for i in range(len(pts)):
    for j in range(len(pts)):
        result[i,j] = fun(pts[i], pts[j])
```

What is the best way to obtain this in a nicer (and more importantly, faster) way?

**EDIT**: using

```
def fun(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
x = np.array(range(10))
y = np.array(range(10))
xv,yv = np.meshgrid(x,y)
result = fun(xv, yv)
```

still raises the same `ValueError`.

Comment: Look at `x>y` for the while arrays.  Can you use that directly?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure I understand what you mean: what do you mean by "the while arrays"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite explicit - suppose you have

```
x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([2,1])
```

such that

```
(x>y) == np.array([0,1])
```

what should be the result of your `if np.array([0,1])` statement? is it true or false? `numpy` is telling you this is ambiguous. Using

```
(x>y).all()
```

or

```
(x>y).any()
```

is explicit, and thus `numpy` is offering you solutions - either any cell pair fulfills the condition, or all of them - both an unambiguous truth value. You have to define for yourself exactly what you meant by *vector x is larger than vector y*.

The `numpy` solution to operate on all pairs of `x` and `y` such that `x[i]>y[j]` is to use mesh grid to generate all pairs:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array(range(10))
>>> y=np.array(range(10))
>>> xv,yv=np.meshgrid(x,y)
>>> xv[xv>yv]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
       9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9])
>>> yv[xv>yv]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8])
```

either send `xv` and `yv` to `fun`, or create the mesh in the function, depending on what makes more sense. This generates all pairs `xi,yj` such that `xi>yj`. If you want the actual indices just return `xv>yv`, where each cell `ij` corresponds `x[i]` and `y[j]`. In your case:

```
def fun(x, y):
    xv,yv=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    return xv>yv
```

will return a matrix where `fun(x,y)[i][j]` is True if `x[i]>y[j]`, or False otherwise. Alternatively

```
return  np.where(xv>yv)
```

will return a tuple of two arrays of pairs of the indices, such that

```
for i,j in fun(x,y):
```

will guarantee `x[i]>y[j]` as well.

Comment: Thank you @kabanus. I understand what the error means. The problem is that I want to get what the loop is doing in a better way. This loop creates an array. If I use `.any` or `.all` then I would get an integer back, rather than an array.

Comment: @splinter Ah, you edited it in, I will answer in a bit.

Comment: yes, I edited some typos from my original posts to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @kabanus, but still, as you can see in the edit I just made, when I pass in meshed arrays, I still get the same error. I am expecting to get an array back.

Comment: @splinter sorry, i wasn't clear. You either send xv[...] yv[..] or generate them in the function- so you do not need the if at all! The arrays are already clean pairs. I will edit later to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [253]: x = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
In [254]: y = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
In [255]: x
Out[255]: array([3, 2, 2, 2, 5])
In [256]: y
Out[256]: array([2, 6, 7, 6, 5])
In [257]: x>y
Out[257]: array([ True, False, False, False, False])
In [258]: np.where(x>y,0,1)
Out[258]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

For a cartesian comparison to these two 1d arrays, reshape one so it can use `broadcasting`:

```
In [259]: x[:,None]>y
Out[259]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False]])
In [260]: np.where(x[:,None]>y,0,1)
Out[260]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Your function, with the `if` only works for scalar inputs.  If given arrays, the `a>b` produces a boolean array, which cannot be used in an `if` statement.  Your iteration works because it passes scalar values.  For some complex functions that's the best you can do (`np.vectorize` can make the iteration simpler, but not faster).

My answer is to look at the array comparison, and derive the answer from that.  In this case, the 3 argument `where` does a nice job of mapping the boolean array onto the desired 1/0. There are other ways of doing this mapping as well.

Your double loop requires an added layer of coding, the broadcasted `None`.

Comment: Forgot about broadcasting, this should be accepted - order of magnitude faster than meshgrid.

Answer (score 1):

For a more complex example or if the arrays you are dealing with are a bit larger, or if you can write to a already preallocated array you could consider `Numba`.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit()
def fun(x, y):
  if x > y:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1

@nb.njit(parallel=False)
#@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def loop(x,y):
  result=np.empty((x.shape[0],y.shape[0]),dtype=np.int32)
  for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[0]):
      result[i,j] = fun(x[i], y[j])
  return result

@nb.njit(parallel=False)
def loop_preallocated(x,y,result):
  for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[0]):
      result[i,j] = fun(x[i], y[j])
  return result
```

**Timings**

```
x = np.array(range(1000))
y = np.array(range(1000))

#Compilation overhead of the first call is neglected

res=np.where(x[:,None]>y,0,1) -> 2.46ms
loop(single_threaded)         -> 1.23ms
loop(parallel)                -> 1.0ms
loop(single_threaded)*        -> 0.27ms
loop(parallel)*               -> 0.058ms
```

*Maybe influenced by cache. Test on your own examples.