# Python: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function which I need to calculate and visualize for a range of arguments.

Here is an example of Jupyter code:

```
%pylab
%matplotlib inline  
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

def testFunc(x):
    a = x[0] - x[1]

    #if a < 0:
    #    a = 0

    b = 2*(a**3)
    return b

X = np.arange(100, 10000, 10)
Y = np.arange(3600, 3900, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = testFunc([X, Y])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

It works fine:
[image]

**BUT** I need to add an additional logic to the function:

```
if a < 0:
    a = 0
```

When I uncomment these lines I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-273b40ed507a> in <module>()
     20 Y = np.arange(3600, 3900, 10)
     21 X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
---> 22 Z = testFunc([X, Y])
     23 
     24 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

<ipython-input-15-273b40ed507a> in testFunc(x)
     11     a = x[0] - x[1]
     12 
---> 13     if a < 0:
     14         a = 0
     15 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

> Does the function apply an array of values in "a"? So it doesn't know which item to compare with "0".
>
> Could you recommend a good way to calculate a function with conditions for
>   range of attributes (with possibility to visualize it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a function to an array using Numpy when the function contains a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594769/applying-a-function-to-an-array-using-numpy-when-the-function-contains-a-conditi)

Comment: Your other question, which is hidden and barely noticeable is also a duplicate - use `a[a<0] = 0`.

Comment: Oh, you answered that post 17 hours ago! It's your day :) Thanks, going to read your answer there...

Comment: Yea, it was really lucky, otherwise I would never have found a duplicate - the title there is misleading so your post is a good signpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options: here are 2 (comment the one you don't want to use):

```
def testFunc(x):
    a = x[0] - x[1]

    # option 1:
    a[a<0] = 0
    # option 2
    a = np.clip(a,0,np.inf)

    b = 2*(a**3)
    return b
```

The result after plotting with your code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, `X` and `Y` are arrays. When you pass the array of arrays to `testFunc` then `a` is an array too. You would need to compare elements of `a` to check if they are less than 0 and then set them to 0 (with the `for` loop for example)

Comment: Thanks! I had a suspicion about that. But I thought that "Z = testFunc([X, Y])" calls testFunc() for each pair of values not for the whole arrays.

Comment: No problem, have a nice day